# change submit method in Django Rest Framework filter modal

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an API built with django-rest-framework, and I'm looking to add filtering to it. I'm following the guide here:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend

I'm seeing two issues:

- the generated form uses `method="post"`. My API currently supports only GET requests, and applying the filter results in "405 method not allowed" error.
- The generated form has no submit button, but the example screenshot does.

my module versions:
Django (1.8)
django-crispy-forms (1.6.0)
django-filter (0.12.0)
django-guardian (1.3.2)
django-mssql (1.7)
django-pyodbc (0.3.0)
django-rest-swagger (0.3.4)
djangorestframework (3.3.2)

I've dug into the templates and it appears theres no easy way to override the form creation.  `base.html` template in rest framework has this at the end

```
{% if filter_form %}
{{ filter_form }}
{% endif %}
```

but its contained in the `{% block body %}`, so to override it with my own template i'd have to also include everything else in the body. This seems lie the wrong solution.

I've also searched through the documentation looking for a place to specify GET instead of POST, and haven't found any mention of this.

I don't want to change the API to handle filters through the POST method. Eventually API will be extended to support a real POST method for actually creating new resources, so applying a filter via POST now would just create other problems down the road.

Is there a way to change the submit method of the modal form? Or a good way to override it with my own modal template without duplicating the rest of the body block?

================
**EDIT**
I've managed to correct the above issues using some jQuery, but this feels rather hackish. If a better solution is out there I'd still be interested in it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // change filter submit method to GET instead of POST
    var form = $('#filtersModal form');
    form.attr('method', 'get');

    // add a submit button to the filter modal dialog
    var cancel = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>');
    var submit = $('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>');

    var footer = $('<div class="modal-footer"></div>');
    footer.append(cancel);
    footer.append(submit);

    form.append(footer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bit late reply.

Extend your filter class from

```
django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet
```

instead of

```
django_filters.FilterSet
```

[Solution described here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3636)